# Is it possible to save the training/validation loss in a list during training in HuggingFace?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I'm currently training my model using the HuggingFace `Trainer` class:

```
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments

args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="codeparrot-ds",
    per_device_train_batch_size=32,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=32,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    eval_steps=5_000,
    logging_steps=5_000,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=8,
    num_train_epochs=1,
    weight_decay=0.1,
    warmup_steps=1_000,
    lr_scheduler_type="cosine",
    learning_rate=5e-4,
    save_steps=5_000,
    fp16=True,
    push_to_hub=True,
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    args=args,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets["train"],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_datasets["valid"],
)
```

This prints the loss during training, but I can't figure out how to save it so that I can plot it later. Note that I need both the training and validation losses during training.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of proceeding might be the following: you can access *training* and *evaluation* losses via the `trainer.state.log_history` object after training. An example below (*accuracy* and *f1* might be ignored as they derive from the *specific* `compute_metrics` function passed as parameter to the `trainer` instance):

[image]

It is a *list of dicts* which contains some logged values per logged step; among the keys of the different dictionaries you should find `'loss'` and `'eval_loss'`, whose values you might retrieve as follows (analogously for validation losses).

```
train_loss = []
for elem in trainer.state.log_history:
    if 'loss' in elem.keys():
        train_loss.append(elem['loss'])
```

The *loss* is computed via the [`.compute_loss()`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/2355e463955a5392c1acf1964d89747e8b146a6f/src/transformers/trainer.py#L2667) method of the `Trainer` class, which you might override for custom behaviour as described at https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.27.1/en/main_classes/trainer#trainer.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Okay got it! So only after the Trainer is done I can save it. That would work as well! And just for completion, can you add the eval loss to some list? I assume from your answer it's just going to be something like `if 'eval_loss' in elem.keys():`?

Comment: @Penguin that's correct. I've added an example of mine which shows how the inner dictionaries are built. You might proceed as for the training loss, replacing `'loss'` with `'eval_loss'`

Answer (score 0):

Adding     `evaluation_strategy = 'steps',` to the training arguments fixed it for me